# Checking if a group of values is inside a given array

Tags: python

I want to check if all the numbers inside "check" is inside a given array "lists", something like this:

```
import sys
lists = [1,2,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]
check = [1,2,3]
for check in lists:
    print True
    sys.exit()
print False
```

However, this prints True all the time except if I make lists = []. Does any one know how this will work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clarification: The order should exactly be [1,2,3] or else should print False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated working

```
s = [True if lists[idx: idx+3] == check else False for idx, item in enumerate(lists[:-2])]
if any(s):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's keep printing `True` because you're printing `True` inside the loop, and if the list is `[]`, it can't iterate because it's empty, so try just:

```
print(all(i in lists for i in check))
```

So whole code is:

```
lists = [1,2,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]
check=[1,2,3]
print(all(i in lists for i in check))
```

**Update:**

```
print(all(i in lists for i in check) and [lists.index(i) for i in check]==range([lists.index(i) for i in check][0],[lists.index(i) for i in check][-1]+1))
```

Comment: It still prints "True" even though [1,2,3] are separated in the "list" array. Ex. [1,2,5,6,3] Nice idea though!

Comment: @Stick1000 What, Really, it returns `False` for me, can you please try again?

Comment: hehehe hurry up @U9-Forward :)

Comment: I used this array to test : [8,2,1,2,4,3,9,0]. It prints True.

Comment: @Stick1000 do you want them in sequence?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Yep.

Comment: @Stick1000 I understand you want them together being the same

Comment: @U9-Forward tick tock

Comment: @vash_the_stampede lol, edited mine :-)

Comment: @Stick1000 Done!!!

Comment: @U9-Forward I been done I made a covfefe too

Comment: @U9-Forward Now we are behind on the 9 new ones .... tick tock

Comment: @U9-Forward haha im cracking up you cannot be serious with that comprhension dude its gotta be past PEP-8 max line length ;) its great but funny how long it is

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Got some stuff to do. Upon testing, it prints False if the array is ex. [8,2,1,2,3,3,9,0].